# Условие в Mysql запросе?

Tags: mysql, php, база-данных, sql

добрый день! есть у меня такое условие в sql запросе

```
AND datetop < DATE_ADD(datetop,INTERVAL 1 DAY)",$db);
```

в базе в поле datetop (DATE) зписывается время в формате date("Y-m-d"); и запрос должен сравнивать - прошел ли 1 день с последнего обновления записи в бод но почему то он не работает с днями - хотя с минутами было все ок...

в общем виде скрипт выглядит вот так

```
if($id != $myrow2['id']) {
$frstat = mysql_query("SELECT datetop, topfr FROM friends WHERE myid='$myrow2[id]'   AND frendid = '$id' AND datetop < datetop + INTERVAL 1 DAY",$db);

if ($frstat == TRUE) {
$frienestat = mysql_fetch_array($frstat);
$datefr = date("Y-m-d");
$frrate = $frienestat['topfr'] + 1;
$resultfrst = mysql_query("UPDATE friends SET datetop='$datefr', topfr='$frrate' WHERE myid='$myrow2[id]' AND frendid = '$id'",$db);
}
}
```

и условие как будто игнорируется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо)) но диагностика не потребовалась - ударившись головой о клавиатуру - задача решилась вот так

```
AND datetop < > date_format(now(), '%Y%m%d')",$db);
```

Answer (score 0):

`AND datetop < datetop + INTERVAL 1 DAY`

Comment: все равно не работает( игнорируется условие

Comment: Приведите пример полного запроса пожалуйста. Условие не может просто брать и игнорироваться, либо записи за этот период отсутствуют, либо выборка неправильно организована.

Comment: Сделайте вот так:
$sql = "SELECT datetop, topfr FROM friends WHERE myid='$myrow2[id]'   AND frendid = '$id' AND datetop < datetop + INTERVAL 1 DAY";
echo $sql;
$frstat = mysql_query($sql,$db);

И потом, выведенный запрос вставьте в phpmyadmin (или в консоль, если вы пользуетесь ей) и посмотрите, какие записи выберутся, а какие нет и почему. Попробуйте сделать такое запрос:
$sql = "SELECT datetop, datetop + INTERVAL 1 DAY as date2, topfr FROM friends WHERE myid='$myrow2[id]'   AND frendid = '$id' AND datetop < datetop + INTERVAL 1 DAY";